# Document in cluster:default are not deletable

Tags: orientdb

Using the documention I store my BLOB using a list of 'Chunk'
They are stored in the Cluster named default with id 3.

If I ask for a chunk like this 
select count(*) from #3:1 I get 1

Then I apply 
delete from #3:1 it return 0

And again
select count(*) from #3:1 I return 1

How can I delete this Document and why delete did not apply ?

Chunk creation :

```
private ODocument save(OrientGraph graph, byte[] content) throws IOException {

        graph.getRawGraph().declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());

        List<ORID> chunks = new ArrayList<ORID>();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            final ORecordBytes chunk = new ORecordBytes();
            chunk.fromInputStream(in, BLOCK_SIZE);
            graph.getRawGraph().save(chunk);
            chunks.add(chunk.getIdentity());
        }

        ODocument record = new ODocument();
        record.field(Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CHUNKS, chunks);
        log.debug("Splitted file to {}", chunks.size());
        graph.getRawGraph().save(record);

        graph.getRawGraph().declareIntent(null);

        return record;

    }
```

Then Reading is ok with

```
ORecordLazyList blocks = doc.field(Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CONTENT);

            if (blocks == null) {
                log.error("No data content for {}", rid);
                return;
            }

            for (OIdentifiable id : (List<OIdentifiable>) blocks) {
                ORecordBytes chunk = (ORecordBytes) id.getRecord();
                chunk.toOutputStream(out);
                chunk.unload();
            }
```

But deleting using the SQL to create a delete commands return 0
and try to Iterating around return a null object

```
String selectChunks = String.format("select %s from %s ",
                    Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CONTENT, resourceID);
            Get(selectChunks, graph).forEach(ids -> {
                OrientVertex rs = (OrientVertex) ids.getProperty(Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CONTENT);
                OrientElementIterable chunks = rs.getProperty(Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CHUNKS);
                chunks.forEach( chunk -> {
                    CHUNK IS NULL !!!! no delete()

                });


            });
```

Using

```
String selectChunks = String.format("select %s.@rid.asString() from %s ",
                Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CONTENT + "." + Resource.RESOURCE_FIELD_CHUNKS, resourceID);
```

Will return the ids but combined with a SQL command return 0 modified entries.

Comment: Hi @Robert Which version are you using? Can you post the code?

Comment: I've completed the question Thanks @MichelaBonizzi First time I'm stuck so long without idea about the causes !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is for raw records, whatever the cluster they're in. The only way I've found so far to delete them is to use [truncate record](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Truncate-Record.html).